# Is std::ofstream.write() faster at writing arrays of chars than individual chars?

Tags: c++, performance, file-io

I want to know if code A is likely to be faster than code B on a majority, or significant number, of hardware/systems.

code A:

```
for(i = 0; i < 4; i ++)
    file.write(array[i], 1);
```

code B:

```
// for(i = 0; i < 1; i ++)
    file.write(array[i], 4);
```

The reason I ask is because I want to be able to write a very long file of 64 bit sequential integers to disk.

Currently the problem I am facing is that my array, which is really a buffer, contains objects which are 8 bytes long, rather than objects of 1 byte which I could very easily write using something like:

```
file.write((char*)(array), size_of_array);
```

I thought of a few solutions, but they all seem pretty unimaginative and bodged to me.

The first was to iterate over 8 bytes:

```
for(j = 0; j < size_of_array; j ++)
    for(i = 0; i < 8; i ++) // 8 == sizeof(uint64_t)
        file.write((char*)(array + i + j), 1);
```

Then I thought, why not just trick write() into writing the 8 bytes for me? Am I allowed to do this?

```
for(j = 0; j < size_of_array; j ++)
    file.write((char*)(array + j), 8);
```

Then I thought, well... Go a step further:

```
file.write((char*)(array), 8 * size_of_array);
```

So my question is really, what is the fastest way to write a very large quantity of data to disk?

By large, I am suggesting writing a buffer containing 4 million objects, and re-filling the buffer and writing again, perhaps to create a file several tens of gigabytes in size.

For those who are interested, this is a parallel processing experiment. Step 1 is to generate the data. This is where I am now. Step 1...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you know this, but there are a few things you should know about streaming objects in this way:

1. This should only be done for POD types.

   Plain Old Data types are types that do not have a constructor.  Reason is that there is logic that presumably sets up resources.  If no resources are allocated, a POD can be initialised using uniform initialization.
2. POD types should not contains references or pointers.

   This is because if you write a pointer to disk and then read it back, will it actually be pointing at the correct something you expected?  Under certain circumstances this *may* be true, but for the most part it isn't.
3. You should use sizeof() operator and not specify the size directly as a constant.

   Classes/structs can have padding within the object that change the size of the object to increase access performance.
4. Binary file generated is endian specific.

   Reading a file generated by this manner will not be readable in the same way without conversion by another system.
5. Binary file generated is compiler specific.

   Again, this has to do with padding.  Different compilers may put padding in different locations.

If these are taken in to account, yes, you could do what you are saying and it should be marginally faster as you are reducing the number of function calls.